# What is the cardinality of a set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm looking for cardinality of $P_{fin}(\Bbb{N})=\{x|x\subset\Bbb{N}$ and $x$ finite$\}$. I was told in my classes that it's $\aleph_0$, but how to prove it?

Comment: Show there is a bijection between $P_{fin}(\mathbb N)$ and $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Show that there is a natural bijection between $P_{\text{fin}}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{N}$; one particularly nice one is more apparent when you work in binary.

Comment: Is it something like: Give me a subset and I'll give you 1... where ... is a number that on i'th position has 1 if i is in set and otherwise 0?

Comment: Yes, that will do nicely! All you have to do to finish the argument is to show that this candidate map is bijective. In this case, it's not too difficult to describe the inverse of the map explicitly.